# How can I temporarily hide the overview when using Alt+Tab?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

**Background:**

I would like to temporarily hide the overview shown when pressing <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>. This can be useful, for instance, when recording a screencast and you wish to hide as many lesser important and distracting elements as possible.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Application switch]

Comment: You want to Alt+Tab without seeing that popup that lists all window groups , did i understand correctly ?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need the CompizConfig Settings Manager:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt install compiz-plugins
```

Open CCSM by going to the dash and type: `ccsm`.
[image]

Click the CCSM icon and:

- Scroll down to <kbd>Ubuntu Unity Plugin</kbd>.
- Choose the tab <kbd>Switcher</kbd>.
- Disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> binding ("Key to start the switcher" )
- Click the <kbd>Back</kbd> button.

#### This way, you can still <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and do see the icons, whereas <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does not show them!

Comment: You might have to log off and back on if it doesn't work immediately.  Please let me know if I need to add this to the answer or not.  **;-)**

Comment: Interesting solution! And disabling the binding still keeps `Alt+Tab` functional without showing the pop-up?

Comment: no, of course not...  That was not one of the prerequisites8  :P  :-)

Comment: I see, thanks! So, I actually replace the keyboard shortcut that produces this pop-up with a shortcut that is not associated with a pop-up but has the same functionality. Clear now. :-)

Comment: If it helps; an accept would be nice...  **:-)**  @RobertOrzanna

Comment: @RobertOrzanna favour returned! Q upvoted!